# Restrictions to talking with the Press during Impeachment trial?

Tags: united-states, senate, trump-impeachment

From my understanding, the impeachment trial of President Trump has *almost* started as the Senate is now voting on the rules of the trial.  I know this might technically need to wait for those rules to pass, but I presume my question shouldn't be that impacted during this process.

Are there any limitations placed on **Senators** during impeachment over what can be said to the Press during this trial?  As this trial is likely to dominate the news cycle for several days at minimum, I'm imagining that as soon as the time allotted is done, several senators will immediately seek out some press members and start pontificating while others seek to disappear.

I may just have inaccurate expectations here.  My concerns mostly stem from a few news articles I saw regarding that press access will be limited during the trial, so I'm curious if those same restrictions might affect the senators as well.

[Link to NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/19/business/media/senate-impeachment-trial-media.html)

[Link to non-Pay wall article](https://www.rollcall.com/news/congress/guidance-press-impeachment-trial-access-restricts-movement)